# downloading csv from nasdaq - no link on download button

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click on the "Download CSV" button here: https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener

However, I've been unable to do so using Python/Selenium (chrome webdriver) and haven't found another method to do so. The problem is that the button does not have an html link that I can scrape as I believe it is a javascript process, hence the screening.

I've checked other q&as but haven't an answer that accomplishes this.

Please help!

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver

# attempt number 1
PATH = "D:\personal_project_4_sec_financial_data\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[name()="tspan" and .="Download CSV"]').click()

# attempt number 2
link = driver.find_element_by_name("Download CSV")
link.click()

driver.find_element_by_class_name("button")
```

first error code:
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[name()="tspan" and .="Download CSV"]"}
(Session info: chrome=xx)

second error code:
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="Download CSV"]"}
(Session info: chrome=xx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out for anybody else searching for the answer. i had to choose the div class two above the button class.

here's the answer code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "D:\personal_project_4_sec_financial_data\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener") 
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
link = driver.find_element_by_class_name("nasdaq-screener__download")
link.click()
```